# Swagger UI missing in Prod for Quarkus App

Tags: maven, swagger, swagger-ui, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

From the Quarkus [docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#dev-mode), `quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true` must be set in the `application.properties` for SwaggerUI to be built in prod.

> By default, Swagger UI is only available when Quarkus is started in
> dev or test mode.

However, even with the property set, Swagger UI is still not built with the app.

- `mvn clean compile quarkus:dev`

```
2024-03-25 17:46:29,725 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) test-process 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.16.10.Final) started in 11.997s. Listening on: http://localhost:8080
2024-03-25 17:46:29,725 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2024-03-25 17:46:29,725 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [cdi, kogito-addon-persistence-rocksdb-extension, kogito-addon-process-svg-extension, kogito-decisions, kogito-predictions, kogito-processes, kogito-rules, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, security, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-health, smallrye-openapi, swagger-ui, vertx]
```

- `mvn clean package; java -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar`

```
2024-03-25 18:05:44,862 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) test-process 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.16.10.Final) started in 1.247s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2024-03-25 18:05:44,862 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated. 
2024-03-25 18:05:44,862 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, kogito-addon-persistence-rocksdb-extension, kogito-addon-process-svg-extension, kogito-decisions, kogito-predictions, kogito-processes, kogito-rules, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, security, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-health, smallrye-openapi, vertx]
```

Note the missing feature `smallrye-openapi, {swagger-ui}, vertx]`

Here is my `application.properties`

```
# Set up for the swagger-ui (Process-defintions)
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.path=/api
quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true
quarkus.swagger-ui.path=/swagger
```

---

Edit:  I copied the project to a [public repo](https://github.com/dekaido/kogito-processes/tree/test-process/backend). Here's the [pom.xml](https://github.com/dekaido/kogito-processes/blob/test-process/backend/pom.xml)

Answer (score 0):

I can not recreate the issue you describe here. When I configure an app as you described here, it starts up with:

```
2024-03-26 17:01:35,811 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) code-with-quarkus 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 3.8.3) started in 0.629s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2024-03-26 17:01:35,817 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated. 
2024-03-26 17:01:35,817 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy-reactive, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-openapi, swagger-ui, vertx]
```

I see you are using a fairly old Quarkus: (2.16.10.Final). Saying that, this feature has been available since pre 1 release.

Does the UI or schema document also not render/download ?

Comment: That's odd.. But yes, it looks like the UI and schema document aren't rendering either. I can't pull up the openapi anywhere with or without the properties path set.

Comment: The version is outdated because I'm running an older example that has dependencies with that version, I believe. I made my own example off of this [kogito-quarkus-example](https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/tree/1.44.1.Final/kogito-quarkus-examples/process-quarkus-example). I tried running with a more recent Quarkus version (3.2.10), and had a lot of javac errors, i.e. `package javax.enterprise.inject does not exist`

Comment: Yes when moving to Quarkus 3 you need to do the javax->jakarta namespace change. I wonder if this is a kogito issue. have you tried with just Quarkus ?

Comment: Hey, I tried with just Quarkus (2) and it seems like the swagger ui still isn't coming up. I copied the project to a public repo. Here's the [pom.xml](https://github.com/dekaido/kogito-processes/blob/test-process/backend/pom.xml)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use it on our production & non-production environment, to actually enable/disable swagger-ui:

`quarkus.swagger-ui.enable=true/false`

And this works.

Comment: still didn't work for me... the openapi is not generating so that's probably the bigger issue

Comment: @dko, you should use above setting in combination with `quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true`.

Comment: yes, i have that line as well.. i added it to the bottom of my `application.properties` in my question above.